# Special Characters do not get displayed properly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm specifically talking about the å, ä and ö in the swedish language. When displayed in paragraphs I use a function to substitute the letters to their HTML entities.

That works fine but now I want to have a function that let's the page admins to change the page title. I want the current title to be preloaded into the inputbox. It's not so easy to read when every ö is translated to it's html entity.

From other answers I'v checked that the files are saved as UTF-8 without BOM in Notepad++.

Database connection are written as:

```
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName); if ($conn->connect_error) { trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR); }
$conn->set_charset("utf-8");
```

In the header of the html document I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
```

Database was created as "latin1_swedish_ci" and in phpmyadmin it displays alright. The database call looks like this. The site works as it should when there is no å, ä and ö. But when there is the input box empty.

include 'db.inc.php';

```
$sql = "SELECT site_admin_title FROM site_admin WHERE site_admin_id = ?"; $id = 1; 
$loadData = $conn->prepare($sql); if($loadData === false) { trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR); }
$loadData->bind_param('i',$id); 
$loadData->execute(); 
$loadData->bind_result($site_admin_title); 
$loadData->fetch(); 
$output_string = $ljusimorker_site_admin_title;
$loadData->close(); 
$conn->close();
echo json_encode($output_string);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Went through that link and nothing helped. The link that was contained in that question too. :(

Comment: I changed the database table to utf8_swedish_ci but that did not help either. Previous was latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `set_charset()` function this way instead (note the omission of the `-` character)

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

Also, you might want to change the character set of your database to UTF-8, as well.

Comment: I have the $conn->set_charset("utf-8"); directly after the database connection. Database now have utf8_swedish_ci

Comment: When I did omit the - they page did not load at all. :(

Comment: That's strange, it should not happen. Did you get a message if you try this? `if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) { printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error); }`

Comment: The database connection now looks like this 

    `$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName); if ($conn->connect_error) { trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR); }
 $conn->set_charset("utf-8"); if(!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) { printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error); }
 $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conn);`

Comment: Now the only output i get is...

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Ett Ljus i M&ouml;rkret - Administration</title>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta charset="utf-8" />`
The the conncetion script runs.

Comment: You shouldn't use SET NAMES.